# AWS: Send certificate info from ELB to EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, sticky-session

When Sticky Sessions are enabled on an AWS ELB it seems that the ELB will terminate SSL ([AWS forum discussing this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=253822)). I need information from the user's certificate to verify some things, so I need the ELB to forward this information to the EC2 instances.

How can I get the ELB to give me the user's certificate information? Is there a way to create custom headers? All I was able to find were these three headers: [Amazon docs on x-forwarded-headers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/x-forwarded-headers.html).

As discussed in the first link I posted another option is persistent sessions. Is this my only option?

Comment: Are you sure you actually mean client certificates? They are very rare in TLS setups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ELB won't give you information regarding the certificate. And you cannot customize/add forwarded headers.

If you need the client certificate, you'll need to use TCP forwarding rather than HTTP/HTTPS.

This way, the ELB will simply forward the connection as-is on to the EC2 instance. It won't terminate the SSL connection, and you won't get sticky sessions.